# regex_match allow '

Tags: regex, validation

I am using regex_match for validation for last names

I have this so far `regex_match[/^[a-zA-Z -]{0,25}+$/]` but I also want to allow `'` for names like O'Neal. I tried this `regex_match[/^[a-zA-Z -\']{0,25}+$/]` but it didnt work

any suggestions?

Thanks,
J

Comment: How doe it not work? What are you getting?

Comment: an error even when I try a normal name like Smith I get an error

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-\'` is an invalid range. You need to put the dash at the end of the character class:

```
/^[a-zA-Z '-]{0,25}$/
```

The `+` is superfluous here (in some regex flavors, it activates "possessive matching", but it's definitely not needed here), as is the backslash.

Also, I suspect that the square brackets around the regex are not syntactically correct in whatever language you're using. (Which one is that, by the way?)

But the real problem is your [trying to validate a name](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) (with a regex, no less).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `\` to escape the `'`, but you probably should put the dash last so it's not creating a range.

Nor do you need the `+` after the `{0,25}`, it's not a valid regex with it.

This works fine for me `^[a-zA-Z '-]{0,25}$`

Comment: However, for a name, why do you have limitations on what characters are valid?  And more importantly, why is 0 length valid, but 26 not?

Comment: You are creating a range from `whitespace` to `'`.

Comment: @RohitJain didn't even see that! Let me fix that

Comment: `a{0,25}+` is perfectly valid in Java or PHP, for example.

Comment: Well, my Regex tool was complaining about it, but it's geared to c# development.